# Kayako SAML plugin: Unable to load User ID: 1

Tags: saml-2.0

It gives error when I want to login with SAML2:

> Unable to load User ID: 1 in
>   ./__swift/apps/base/models/User/class.SWIFT_User.php:109

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately It there is a bug on Kayako SAML plugin and there should be a (dummy) user with ID:1 in the kayako DB